# Connect to a websites WebSocket server that isn't mine

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

As the title says I'm trying to connect to a website their WebSocket to get live updates. However I've tried everything, and all it does is the WebSocket immediately disconnects after connecting. I've checked their version of the connection to the WebSocket, they do not reply with anything after the `onopen` event. I've tried setting the origin in case of them not accepting any connections from origins other than their own.

I'm trying to do this within NodeJS with the `ws` module. I'm trying to reach the WebSocket of https://rollbit.com (wss://ws.rollbit.com/);

**Code**

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');    
const ws = new WebSocket('wss://ws.rollbit.com/', {
  origin: 'https://rollbit.com'
});

ws.on('open', function open() {
  console.log('connected');
});

ws.on('close', function close() {
  console.log('disconnected');
});
```

I've also attempted to do this from within the browser, it works perfectly when I do it from the console when being on their site, when changing to another site and running the code there - it fails. I've tried cookies as well..

**Result**

```
connected
disconnected
```

Any ideas of what I'm missing here?

Comment: You could be hitting some kind of protection to discourage unauthorized agents from connecting. Connection works from the site console because it is within the same domain.

Comment: @EriksKlotins that's what I was thinking, but I'm pretty sure you can fake the origin using the `ws` module, and that's what I tried without any luck.

Comment: If you are using it in the browser, you cannot fake origin in the browser due to (obvious) security reasons.  You may be able to do it with a custom extension or a proxy application of some sort, but allowing the faking of origin would cause all kinds of awful exploits.  Technically what you are trying to achieve is a security exploit.

Comment: @user120242 oh, I actually never knew you could completely block out any other sources from accessing WebSockets - I just kind of assumed it as when using the module `ws` from within NodeJS you can actually add the `origin` key to the settings.

Comment: oh, ya, I guess that deserves explanation. so the gist of it is, in the context of Node.js you are running code or an application in the context of a user space program, not like in a browser where it is assumed to be sandboxed and the user is supposed to be given a certain level of safety, such that for example it is expected that the ability to manipulate another website where the user might have sensitive information should be protected (or I guess protectable?) from other websites (hence the existence of XSS exploits and the need to prevent them).

Comment: therefore it is only natural that in the context of browsers, information like the "origin" header should reliably report where they are sourced from, so that websites can protect their users, and users can expect that they can be protected by default (assuming something outside the sandbox hasn't tampered with the browser or its output).    Anyways, you can put your own server, a proxy, in between the websocket server and the browser, and fake the origin header.   For example set up a nginx reverse proxy and use: `proxy_set_header Origin https://rollbit.com;`

Comment: @MartijnEbbens how did u test the code in the browser? Because basically you cant use require in the console of a browser.